Query a data extension that is present in the parent business unit(Local level) from a child business unit
The DE named "****" is located locally at the Parent BU. However, I am able to access it using the "ENT." prefix when running a query in the child BU account. How is this possible, given that the DE is not located in a shared location?
Note: I can only access this DE, which is located at the local level in the Parent BU.

Can you double check if a Data Extension with the same name exists as a Shared Data Extension? Also, are you referring to a Data Extension you manually created or one of the Data Views?

unless the other comment already solved this; please specify, are we maybe talking about a synchronized data extension? Are you using Marketing Cloud Connect multi-org by any chance?

@Jonas Lamberty- I'm using Marketing Cloud Connect, but the Data Extension I'm referring to is not a synchronized Data Extension.
to add on more details: We are using the Data Extension for autosuppression, which we created automation at the Parent BU level to capture hard bounces and blocks on a daily basis.

@Stijn Hoste - Checked! DE Is only located locally at the Parent BU.

When you say auto-suppression, are you referring to "auto-suppression configurations" (which technically speaking, are a kind of data extension) or is this just a descriptive term for what you use a basic DE for?

@Jonas Lamberty & @Stijn Hoste - I got an answer:
If the Data Extension type is CONTEXTUAL_SUPPRESSION_LISTS and it's created at the LOCAL LEVEL within the Parent BU, it can be accessed across the child BUs as well.

Next time, please mention that you are talking about an auto suppression list. Nevertheless, good to know.
